# How to create a small (Single Machine) domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, domain, active-directory

I am trying to install Virtual Machine Manager so I can test out the Lab Mananger portion of VS2010.

The Virtual Machine Manager Requires a Domain to install to.  Is there an easy way to setup a domain that will satisfy this requirement?  It would just be a domain for my server to join (no other computers would be joining it).

**Background info if you are interested:**
My server is a Windows Server 2008 x64.  The server is not on site with my company's domain.  I had planned to use a VPN (Cisco VPN Client 5) to connect to my company domain.  However, Cisco VPN Client 5 does not support x64, and I don't have the newer version that does.  (And I am not knowledgeable enough about VPNs to configure one of the free ones (like ShrewSoft).)

Comment: Thanks for the great answers.  It IS just for Development and prototyping.  It will not be able to go to any kind of prod env (I am installing it on a second partition on my laptop).  I do hope to show how powerful the Lab Manager can be so that we do get a prod version. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to install Active Directory on your server, which means running dcpromo on it.  Have a look at the video in [**this post**](http://windowsmvp.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!80195647FE07388F!570.entry).

That said, I would recommend you install a second member server if you are able to and join it to the domain in order to install VMM.  It's typically not such a good idea to play with application level services on Windows domain controllers.

Comment: I feel like the second server is probably overkill in this case seeing as it is a development only environment with no other machines connecting to the domain.

Comment: It could very well be, but I've gotten bitten by it before...  Might just be a bit of a bitter taste in my mouth :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to run DCPROMO on the existing server and get a new box and set that up as part of the domain and use it as a test server.  You certainly want to have at least two domain controllers.

Comment: I don't think there's any need for a second controller if all he's doing is testing with a single virtual machine. It's not a production network.

Comment: If it's just development (and doesn't sneak into production), a second domain controller is just addt'l licensing cost, complication, and ultimately is needless. If the development AD forest is that important, back it up and restore it in the event of failure. It's doubtful that downtime on a development AD forest would be a big deal (and, if it is, it's not "development" anymore!).